# Cable shielding through 4 pin GX12 connector, is it possible?

Tags: usb

I'm in the process of making a custom USB cable. I have some GX12 4 pin connectors lying around so I figured I'd use those, but I'm not sure if they will work or if an additional 5th pin is needed.

One end of the cable will attach to a 5 pin JST connector, where one of the pins is attached to the shield of the cable that came with the device originally.

This is what the cable would look like: [USB Type A] --> [GX12 Male] --> [GX12 Female] --> [5 pin JST]

Would it be a bad idea to route the shielding through the GX12 connector housing or is this totally fine?

Comment: What data rate and, if a high data rate is needed, what is the characteristic impedance of the GX12 connectors? Have you checked this? Do you need to check this?

Comment: @Andyaka probably too high impendance in the connector... Is that a deal breaker? Data rate I don't really know, the device is a keyboard.

Comment: I don't know if it's a deal breaker or not but, likely, someone will.

Comment: "Would it be a bad idea to route the shielding through the GX12 connector housing" - this would be a standard engineering idea.

Comment: @Ale..chenski haha not saying it’s good or bad though? I’m not an engineer myself, as you may have guessed 